# Taking means over `sam` and `dup`

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to take the means over the columns `sam` and `dup` of the following dataset:

```
    fat co lab sam dup
1  0.62  1   1   1   1
2  0.55  1   1   1   2
3  0.34  1   1   2   1
4  0.24  1   1   2   2
5  0.80  1   1   3   1
6  0.68  1   1   3   2
7  0.76  1   1   4   1
8  0.65  1   1   4   2
9  0.30  1   2   1   1
10 0.40  1   2   1   2
11 0.33  1   2   2   1
12 0.43  1   2   2   2
13 0.39  1   2   3   1
14 0.40  1   2   3   2
15 0.29  1   2   4   1
16 0.18  1   2   4   2
17 0.46  1   3   1   1
18 0.38  1   3   1   2
19 0.27  1   3   2   1
20 0.37  1   3   2   2
21 0.37  1   3   3   1
22 0.42  1   3   3   2
23 0.45  1   3   4   1
24 0.54  1   3   4   2
25 0.18  2   1   1   1
26 0.47  2   1   1   2
27 0.53  2   1   2   1
28 0.32  2   1   2   2
29 0.40  2   1   3   1
30 0.37  2   1   3   2
31 0.31  2   1   4   1
32 0.43  2   1   4   2
33 0.35  2   2   1   1
34 0.39  2   2   1   2
35 0.37  2   2   2   1
36 0.33  2   2   2   2
37 0.42  2   2   3   1
38 0.36  2   2   3   2
39 0.20  2   2   4   1
40 0.41  2   2   4   2
41 0.37  2   3   1   1
42 0.43  2   3   1   2
43 0.28  2   3   2   1
44 0.36  2   3   2   2
45 0.18  2   3   3   1
46 0.20  2   3   3   2
47 0.26  2   3   4   1
48 0.06  2   3   4   2
```

The output should be this:

```
  lab co     fat
1   1  1 0.58000
2   2  1 0.34000
3   3  1 0.40750
4   1  2 0.37625
5   2  2 0.35375
6   3  2 0.26750
```

These are both in the form of .RData files.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example with part of the data you posted:

```
dt = read.table(text = "
fat co lab sam dup
0.62  1   1   1   1
0.55  1   1   1   2
0.34  1   1   2   1
0.24  1   1   2   2
0.80  1   1   3   1
0.68  1   1   3   2
0.76  1   1   4   1
0.65  1   1   4   2
0.30  1   2   1   1
0.40  1   2   1   2
0.33  1   2   2   1
0.43  1   2   2   2
0.39  1   2   3   1
0.40  1   2   3   2
0.29  1   2   4   1
0.18  1   2   4   2
", header= T)

library(dplyr)

dt %>%
  group_by(lab, co) %>%           # for each lab and co combination
  summarise(fat = mean(fat)) %>%  # get the mean of fat
  ungroup()                       # forget the grouping

# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#     lab    co   fat
#   <int> <int> <dbl>
# 1     1     1  0.58
# 2     2     1  0.34
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there any way I can directly input the .RData file instead of using text? So, say the .RData file is called `dat1<-x.RData`.

Comment: When you open a new R script in R studio you can import the .RData file by clicking on it. The dataset imported from yout .RData file should have a name which you can use instead of `dt` in my example.

Comment: Yes, so if you want to save the new table (i.e. the one with the averages) you should save it when you create it. You can use something like `dt2 = dt %>% ...`